# JQuery fadeIn not working with fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fade

I'm trying to make a carousel using fadeIn and fadeOut but the first picture fades out while the next picture simply appears after. I want to make a smooth transition. I also structured this code according to what I learned from Codecademy. I can't really determine what went wrong. I'm using Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
        <div class = "slidingPhotos" align="center">
            <div class = "slide active-item">
                <div class = "photo1">
                    <img src = "Images/mainImage.jpg"></img>
                </div>
                <div class = "description">
                    <h3> Welcome to O-Grocery! Your #1 Online Grocery Store </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "slide ">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "photo1">
                        <img src = "Images/mainImage3.jpg"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "description">
                        <h3> You have a thousand products to choose from at O-Grocery! </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "slide">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "photo1">
                        <img src = "Images/mainImage2.jpg"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "description">
                        <h3> You can guarantee 100% freshness of goods! </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="footer" align="center">
            <div class = "dots">
                <div class = "arrow-prev">
                    <a href ="#"><img src = "Images/arrow-prev.png"></img></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="slider-dots">
                    <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
                    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
                    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
                </ul>
                <div class = "arrow-next">
                    <a href ="#"><img src = "Images/arrow-next.png"></img></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut('slow').removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });
```

Comment: Use the callbacks. Animating methods have callback function which is called when the animation is complete.

Comment: See answer with sample code below; you need to make second animation wait for first one to finish.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Oh. I can't really do it at the same time? In Codecademy. They do it at the same time and the effect looks good.

Comment: You can blend them, sure, so that at one point in between you see both, is that what you mean? Post the link to Codeacademy please

Comment: Yes. This is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation via `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` is asynchronous and since you are starting both animations at the same time, by the time the first thing fades out the second thing is already done fading in. You basically just need to force a delay on the second animation somehow, either by making sure that it is called after the first animation completes, or by knowing that the `slow` speed in jQuery is 600 milliseconds. (Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You can get more control over animation by using `.animate()` but you can also fake it in this case by using `setTimeout()` after the first animation to make sure that it can finish before the second animation begins.

You can run this example right from the answer:

```js
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut('slow').removeClass('active-slide');
    setTimeout(function(){ nextSlide.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active-slide'); }, 300);

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });
```

```css
.slide { display: none; }
.slide.active-item {display:block;}
img {display:none;}
a {display:inline-block;background-color:#666;color:#fff;padding: 15px;margin:10px;}
.dots div {display:inline-block; }
.slidingPhotos { height: 55px; width: 500px; margin-bottom: 10px; display:block;background-color: #ccc; }
.slide { position: absolute; top: 10; height: 55px; width: 500px; text-align: center; color:Blue;font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,"sans serif"; font-size:14px;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class = "slidingPhotos">
            <div class = "slide active-item active-slide">
                <div class = "photo1">
                    <img src = "Images/mainImage.jpg"></img>
                </div>
                <div class = "description">
                    <h3> Welcome to O-Grocery! Your #1 Online Grocery Store </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "slide ">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "photo1">
                        <img src = "Images/mainImage3.jpg"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "description">
                        <h3> You have a thousand products to choose from at O-Grocery! </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "slide">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "photo1">
                        <img src = "Images/mainImage2.jpg"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "description">
                        <h3> You can guarantee 100% freshness of goods! </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="footer" align="center">
            <div class = "dots">
                <div class = "arrow-prev">
                    <a href ="#">PREVIOUS<img src = "Images/arrow-prev.png"></img></a>
                </div>
                <div class = "arrow-next">
                    <a href ="#">NEXT<img src = "Images/arrow-next.png"></img></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I want it to be almost done at the same time. That one element fades in and one to fade out at the same time so that the screen wouldn't be that dull.

Comment: So you can just tweak the timeout milliseconds, or use `.animate()` with `step` as suggested in the jQuery API page for `animate`

Comment: Updated example to show the smooth fading where you can see the blended text in the [be]tween frames. (Note that I hid all your images with CSS just to avoid the broken image link, but you could blend images this way as well). As a side note, since you are using jQuery already I would recommend instead of reinventing the wheel use a carousel library like Slick, it's pretty good, see here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** observer the effects of `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` at the same time as the functions are asynchronous:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut('slow').removeClass('active-slide'); <-|
nextSlide.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active-slide');        <-| starts together
```

Use `animate()` with `step` option. `step` can accept a callback function for each animated property of each animated element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value of the property before it is set.

Comment: You CAN start them at the same time because they are asynchronous, but in this case they both completed at the same time for the same element.